# How to debug Java code in JRuby rails application

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby

On my rails part I use some Java-code packed into jars, I extract the class in ruby as follows: `beanA = self.bean_factory().getBean("BeanA")`, where `bean_factory` connects to the database and set up the spring context. The problem is when I'm running the application in debug mode I can't go inside that java object: `beanA.method1()` while the method invocation itself works OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to debug the Java libraries unless your IDE understands Java and the libraries in question were compiled with debug information enabled.  You'd also need to be using an IDE that understood both Ruby and Java, and the only one I can think of that would do this would be IntelliJ with the RubyMine plugin, unless Eclipse now supports Ruby as well.

Comment: I've got the IntelliJ idea Ultimate with that plugin, where I can easily debug Rails application and dive in rails code, but not in java dependencies. Do you suggest packaging those jars with debug info?