# Is it possible to debug the java code inside a jruby app, in visual studio code?

Tags: java, ruby, visual-studio-code, jruby

I have a JRuby app which has a controller, in which I call a method of a Java class. As far as I understood, I need to compile the java code (.java file) into either a .class file or a .jar file to be able to reference it in my controller. I have made it work by compiling the java code into a .class file and calling the java class method from my controller. However, compiling the java code and creating a binary file (.class) prevents me from debugging the java code within the JRuby app. My question is, is there a way to be able to put breakpoints in my java code when running the JRuby app and inspect the values?

I am new to Java and any help would be appreciated.
P.S. I am using visual studio code as my IDE.

Comment: Great question! Latest information I've been able to find directly is from 9 years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25238874/3784008. Most suggestions elsewhere are to use something other than VSCode which is itself fairly recent. MRI hasn't really had first-class support in VSCode either until Shopify released https://github.com/Shopify/vscode-shopify-ruby. JRuby is going to be tough to get nailed down in VSCode, I think.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)